# Автоматическая смена фона в зависимости от месяца и дня

Tags: javascript, css

Всем привет! Такая задача, нужно, чтобы фон сайта менялся в зависимости от месяца и дня, которые у пользователя (а не у сервера). Например, чтобы с 25 декабря по 20 января был праздничный фон, естественно, что он уже располагается в папке на сервере с остальными изображениями. Вот код в стилях, который сейчас отображает фон:

```
body{   
background-image: url("/images/bg1.jpg");   
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
webkit-background-size: cover;
moz-background-size: cover;
o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

-ms-user-select: none; 
-moz-user-select: none; 
-webkit-user-select: none; 
user-select: none; 
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать

Comment: А как вы думаете это можно сделать? Может какие скрипты написать или что?

Comment: вот это *в зависимости от месяца и дня, которые у пользователя (а не у сервера)*  заставило меня задуматься....

Comment: это касается дня конечно) у некоторых новый год уже наступил, а у других еще нет

Comment: Ну с помощью js проверяй текущую дату и меняй, всё.

Comment: http://javascript.ru/Date - Date поддерживает как методы для работы в зоне UTC (GMT+0), так и методы для работы с местным временем.
Местное время - это то, которое установлено на компьютере, на котором выполняется яваскрипт, то бишь пользователя.

Comment: http://kuli4kam.net/topic/1813-smena-fona-saita-v-zavisimosti-ot-vremeni-sutok/

Answer (score 1):

Можно на JavaScript:

```js
function setNewYearBg() {
  var now = new Date(),
      month = now.getMonth(),
      day = now.getDate();
  if( (month == 11 && day >=25) || (month == 0 && day <= 20) ) {
    document.body.classList.add('newyear');
  }
}
setNewYearBg();
```

```css
body{   
background-image: url(https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/57453290e77cd154e64d8634.jpg);   
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size: cover;
}

body.newyear {
  background-image: url(https://be-ledy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/chto-nelzya-delat-v-novogodnyuyu-noch.jpg);
}
```